# Javascript : How to add comma to string element in interface

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi have below structure for user interface -

```
export interface IUser {
  EMPLOYEE_NAME :string,
  EMPLOYEE_PID : string
}
```

At a point in a code , I am receiving array of IUser - IUser[] with multiple employeenames and their pids.

Eg.

```
{EMPLOYEE_NAME:'XYZ',EMPLOYEE_PID :'A123'},
{EMPLOYEE_NAME:'ABC',EMPLOYEE_PID :'B123'},
```

**I want to fetch comma seperated PIDs - 'A123','B123'**

I tried with map and foreach but not able to loop properly as its interface.

Comment: *"I tried with"* - can you include your attempt in a snippet?  See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Array.prototype.map** and **Array.prototype.join** to achieve.

```js
let data = [{EMPLOYEE_NAME:'XYZ',EMPLOYEE_PID :'A123'},
{EMPLOYEE_NAME:'ABC',EMPLOYEE_PID :'B123'}];

let result = data.map(x => x.EMPLOYEE_PID).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

If you want to wrap the ids in comma

```js
let data = [
  {EMPLOYEE_NAME:'XYZ',EMPLOYEE_PID :'A123'},
  {EMPLOYEE_NAME:'ABC',EMPLOYEE_PID :'B123'}
];
let result = data.map(x => `'${x.EMPLOYEE_PID}'`).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Array.prototype.map.call` to achieve.

```
    const data = [
     {EMPLOYEE_NAME:'XYZ',EMPLOYEE_PID :'A123'},
     {EMPLOYEE_NAME:'ABC',EMPLOYEE_PID :'B123'}
    ];

    Array.prototype.map.call(data,
        function(item) { 
            return item['EMPLOYEE_PID']; 
        }
    ).join(",");
```

**Output** - 'A123,B123'